# Embedded font installs and gets drawn by Graphics correctly but cannot be used in Windows Forms controls

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

I've embedded font in my app using `PrivateFontCollection`. I can install fonts and then use them in a `Graphics` object perfectly. The problem is that the font name doesn't get recognized in my form Controls `Font` property. I want to make sure that if I create a `Font` object like `new Font("MyFontName",...)` the name `MyFontName` is recognized and the loaded font gets used.

**What I did:**

```
public FontFamily InstallFromMemory(byte[] bytes)
{
    // Get unsafe bytes
    GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // install for gdi+
    Collection.AddMemoryFont(pointer, bytes.Length);
    var result = Collection.Families[Collection.Families.Length - 1];

    // install for gdi

    // do the unmanaged font (Windows 2000 and later)
    uint cFonts;
    var r = AddFontMemResourceEx(bytes, bytes.Length, IntPtr.Zero, out cFonts);
    if (r.ToInt64() == 0)
        throw new Exception("Failed to install the font.");

    // free unsafe bytes
    pinnedArray.Free();

    Families.Add(result.Name, result);
    return result;
}
```

It gives no error but it doesn't work either. Is `AddFontMemResourceEx` even the right API function to call? What should I do to get my intended result?

Comment: Standard bug, you cannot call Free() until your program can no longer use the font and you have called PrivateFontCollection.Dispose().  That makes using  GCHandle.Alloc() a very bad idea, use Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem instead and copy the array data.  That makes the class is very clunky, only decent way to use it is to create the fonts up front and not bother releasing them again.  It all disappears when your program ends.

Comment: @HansPassant: You mean I called pinnerArray.Free()? because I didn't dispose PrivateFontCollection at all.